# Multiple UICollectionView layers on same cells

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This might be a compound question, so please bear with me.

Upon finishing loading objects from Parse and populating the CollectionViewCells with them, it shows a strange bouncing animation even if I explicitly set `self.collectionView?.bounces = false`. Moreover, the labels are clearly drawing over each other and you can see a picture bouncing under another.

Here are the bugs I'm seeing:

https://youtu.be/q306SGM_tLE and https://youtu.be/gK9HN877nRo

This is how I handle the cells:

```swift
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("itemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    let nameLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 13)
    let priceLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 10)

    var priceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40))
    var name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 180, self.view.frame.size.width/2-5, 20))
    var unitLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width/2-5, 20))
    var addToCartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 220, 100, 30))

    if self.productImageArray.count != 0 {


        var image = self.productImageArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as UIImage
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 187.5, height: 180)

        name.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            string: self.productArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("name") as NSString,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()])

        var price:Float = self.productArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("price_tipsy") as Float
        priceLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        priceLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            string: "$\(price)",
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()])

        unitLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            string: self.productArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("unit") as NSString,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()])

        addToCartButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(
            string: "ADD TO CART",
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : priceLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()]),
            forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addToCartButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        addToCartButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        addToCartButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        addToCartButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5



        cell.addSubview(imageView)
        cell.addSubview(name)
        cell.addSubview(priceLabel)
        cell.addSubview(unitLabel)
        cell.addSubview(addToCartButton)


    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my UI

[image]

and its Debug View Hierarchy

[image]

after a few times of pull to refresh, Debug View Hierarchy shows multiple layers on the same cell, number of layers corresponding to number of refreshes.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Here is my custom cell class:

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

func setup(frameWidth:CGFloat, image: UIImage, name: NSString, price:Float, unit:NSString) {

    let nameLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 13)
    let priceLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 10)

    var priceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40))
    var nameLabel = UILabel()
    var unitLabel = UILabel()
    var addToCartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 220, 100, 40))


    nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 180, frameWidth/2-5, 20))
    unitLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, frameWidth/2-5, 20))

    nameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    unitLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: frameWidth/2-5, height: 180)

    nameLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
        string: name,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()])

    priceLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    priceLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
        string: "$\(price)",
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()])

    unitLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
        string: unit,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : nameLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()])

    addToCartButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(
        string: "ADD TO CART",
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : priceLabelFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()]),
        forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    addToCartButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    addToCartButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    addToCartButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    addToCartButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5


    self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    self.contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(priceLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(unitLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(addToCartButton)



}
```

And in terms of UICollectView class, `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` is called when RefreshController is pulled, and here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("itemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ShopCell
    cell.setup(self.view.frame.width, image: UIImage(), name: "AAA", price: 20.00, unit: "aaa")
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: When you scroll, and the cells are reused, you're adding subviews to cells that already have those subviews. Create a custom cell, and add those subviews in the storyboard, or do it in code by adding them in the cell's init method. Adding subviews in cellForItemAtIndexPath is not a good idea (unless you're adding subviews to some cells and not others based on the indexPath).

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the comment! After subclassing UICollectionViewCell, I still have similar errors, could it be from another incorrect implementation (reloadData, etc)?

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong without seeing the code you are currently using. Edit your question to show what you are doing in the cell class as well as the collection view controller class.

Comment: @rdelmar updated question, it's a bit long but thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't really change anything by doing it the way you are; you moved the code to the cell class, but you call that code from cellForRowAtIndexPath, so functionally, it's the same as you had before. The subviews should be added in the cell's init method which is only called once when the cell is created (not when it's reused). Any data that you add to the cell like the image, name, price, and unit should be added in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I knew it's late, but do you still need help?

Comment: @Jerome thanks but I figured that one out. Fell in love with iOS development and became an iOS developer.

Comment: What was your solution @udjat?